# Updating/Refreshing Child Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some data displayed in a child action and I'm using some buttons to manipulate the data like so:

Index.cshtml

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#RefreshView").onclick(function () {
         $("#viewer").load(@(Html.Action("ViewData", "Home", new { data = Model }));
      }); 
</head>
<body>
   <div style="float:left;" id="viewer">
      @Html.Action("ViewData", new { data = Model })
   </div>
   <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="button" id="RefreshView" value="Refresh" />
   </div>
</body>
```

Ideally, I'd want the button click to go through the child action again and refresh the data. I've looked for solutions, but most of the deal with `Html.Partial`, which I don't want to use because I want to perform the data manipulation in the child action as they are cosmetic and temporary changes that I don't want saved.

Comment: You'll need to AJAX the result as a partial page update

Comment: Why would using a partial save anything?

Comment: @beautifulcoder So I implemented the AJAX (code to be posted), but for some reason, the onclick is getting called automatically on load instead of when I click on the button.

Comment: That is a separate issue, I'll answer your original question thou

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX for this to do partial page updates, for example:

```
$(function () {
    $('#RefreshView').click(function () {
        $.post('/Url', { /* JSON goes here */ }, function (data) {
            /* The 'Url' points to the partial and returns a View */
            $('#viewer').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This registers the callback on the `ready` DOM event and fires when you click the button. `html` partially updates the page on the registered success callback.

Also, you should add the `jquery` tag to this question.